# Distributed TensorFlow, using a random seed

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am using the [distributed version of MNIST](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py) for running multinode distributed CPU based TensorFlow. It works fine but I cannot get reproducible results, I tried following the random seeds set up following [random_seed.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py) and the other SO answers i.e. adding the ts.set_random_seed before the graph is created, and per operation as well, but that doesn't work. 
How can I achieve working with a random seed for multi node tensorflow?

Comment: Did you set the flag `--sync_replicas` to true?

Comment: Yes, I did set to true, but I still get no deterministic runs. I am using tensorflow version 1.2, something else I could try?

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/99a38ffd9d77c55ca6d0c373c6d4b72686284ac5/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py#L94) takes an optional seed, but it isn't set in the script by default: `mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments but that doesn't seem to work. You can see where I added the seed to the script [here](https://gist.github.com/renato2099/07a693a719098fb82f4bb5da795a7fc4) Could it also be that because different workers run at different speeds I always end up getting different results? I mean the final accuracy is similar but the losses on each round is always different for each worker every time I execute the script.

Comment: Could you please help me out here @mrry? any other comments/suggestions would be much much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is a super old post, but I was wondering about this myself. My guess is that getting deterministic results in distributed TensorFlow is impossible because there is no way to specify which workers will receive which batches from the data feed, but maybe someone more knowledgeable could confirm.